# Why do AuthType Basic directives not work in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-basic-authentication, clearos

I have a web server running on ClearOs 6. I would like to protect a couple of directories using .htaccess, but I do not seem to be prompted for a password at all.
Relevant bits of conf file are:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
LogLevel debug
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNOExec
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AddType text/html .php
    AddHandler php5-script .php
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file in folder /var/www/html/hidden looks like this:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/users
AuthGroupFile /var/www/group
AuthName ByPassword
Authtype Basic
Require user johnsmith
```

/var/www/users:

```
johnsmith:GibberishChangedForHackers
```

/var/www/group is empty.

If I attempt to access hidden/index.html, I am allowed access with no password prompt. The error log says nothing. The access log shows a normal access.

If, instead of using .htaccess, I add the same auth directives in a `<Directory /var/www/html/hidden>` element, I am asked for a password, ao authorisation does actually work.

If I add an invalid directive to .htacess, I get a server error, and an entry in the error log, so .htaccess **is** getting parsed by Apache.

Comment: What is your exact clearOS 6 version ? i am not able to reproduce your issue. Have you double-checked for any typo for `.htaccess` filename ?

Comment: `/etc/issue` says `ClearOS Community release 6.5.0 (Final)`. I know it is loading .htaccess, because if I put an illegal directive in there, it reports it when accessing the page.